# AWS MWAA (Managed Apache Airflow); Programmatically enable DAGs

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

We are using AWS MWAA. We add our DAG.py files to our S3 bucket programatically. They then show up in the UI. However, they are "OFF" and you must click the "ON" button to start them.

EDIT: Also we may sometimes want to turn a DAG that's ON to OFF (programatically)

I am looking to do this programmatically, however I cannot figure out to.

The API does not seem to have it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-actions-resources.html

Boto does not seem to have it:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/mwaa.html

Is it possible to manipulate a DAGs status from OFF/ON ON/OFF via API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not doable via API but you can use [is_paused_upon_creation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/75603160848e4199ed368809dfd441dcc5ddbd82/airflow/models/dag.py#L264) this flag specifies if the dag is paused when created for the first time. If the dag exists already, this flag will be ignored.

You can set `is_paused_upon_creation=False` in the DAG contractor.

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    is_paused_upon_creation=False,
)
```

Another option is to do it via [unpause CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#unpause):

```
airflow dags unpause [-h] [-S SUBDIR] dag_id
```

Comment: if a job is enabled, how do I toggle it though, without deleting it and re creating it, which will make us lose history?

Comment: @Tommy you can do that via CLI https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#unpause or via the UI

Comment: Yes. See https://dnx.solutions/how-to-use-apache-airflow-cli-with-amazon-mwaa/

Comment: how does the CLI work? as in, if the CLI works, there must be an API for it, no?